# Automate the process of publishing Android app

Tags: android, automation

We have several Android apps and found that the process of uploading apps for each release via [Android Developers website](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) *slow* and *ineffective*.  We like to automate the process.  To be more clear, we have automation for compiling and building the apps, it's a matter of uploading them to Android Market and fill in the app details for publishing.  This is where we are left with **manual publishing**.

I am interested to learn how people *automate this publishing process*?  Does Google have a web service of some sort for publishing Android App on Android Market?

Comment: I would suggest you do that manually. How many apps do you have that you can't take the time to write a proper 350 character descripton of them?

Comment: @Falmarri I think he is talking about updating the apps, not creating a new one.

Comment: In what way is it ineffective?

Comment: It's ineffective because it's outside the build process. A publishing process integrated with the build tools could: manage the complicated checklist for exporting the app (with the correct signature and with licensing enabled); get the right screen shots; version control of the verbiage; etc.

Answer (score 3):

> Does Google have a web service of some sort for publishing Android App on Android Market?

No, sorry.