# Android - Publish app use ant script

Tags: android, publish

Do we have api to publish app not from Publisher Console Web?
E.g. I have a nightly build system (using ant) and I would like to have it publish the app automatically for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it would seem that this is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4149313/1101070) currently possible as Google does not have a web-service or API capable of this.

And it follows that if this can't be done via a script/program, it can't be done through Ant.

Comment: Yes. The only way can do is I have post the method manually with a web view embeded in the application.

Answer (score 2):

Hello Tran Hoang Duy Anh

As it seems, there is no comfortable way to publish automagically. Right now I am writing my Bachelor Thesis researching a way to have some way of automation. The title is: "Continuous Delivery for Android Apps" (in german). My approach after asking the big Internet and finding nothing appropriate is, using [Selenium Webdriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) as a base for my work, which is a Testing framework for Browser automation etc. You have to filter "clickables" via using XPath and you'll get behind what I mean.

What I do right now is to create a piece of Java software, which will be acting as a Jenkins or Maven servant. I am creating now an API to control this Google Developer "Pseudo" Console. This will do the job for me to publish even nightly builds.

For I am not sure, if there isn't truly no solution in the wild, but this means you have to create your own API right now - perhaps using Webdriver as one way to communicate and control the PlayStore.

I hope this helps you a bit. But be warned, if Google decides to change their Layout, your Tool would be broken, this is quite too tightly coupled, but maybe I'll find a better solution. ;-)

Best regards,
Semo

Comment: yes. thanks for your help. Google is changing their play console layout :) FYI: we decide to manual publish instead using some macro tools and build our all internal store for beta testers :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tran Hoang Duy Anh. Well, I need to create a solution like described above, because my Professor and his company needs it. They release more than 8 Versions a day for different customers, each having it's own special app, which needs to be maintained. And he hasn't got that much Human Ressource (bad word) to do that. That is why, I am coding it instead. But yes, right now it seems to me, that you are right though.

Best regards,